# code only working when run from console

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I am using a responsive slider and want to make clickable links over the images.

I found this plugin to make responsive image maps
https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps/blob/master/jquery.rwdImageMaps.js

the slide looks like this, I have the link over an image map

```
  <li>
<img src="slide_2.png" usemap="#Image-Maps_5201211121032528"   />
<map id="_Image-Maps_5201211121032528" name="Image-Maps_5201211121032528">
<area shape="rect" coords="282,120,369,153" href="http://canvas.landsend.com/canvas/arrivals/blogger/index3.html"/>
</map> 
    </li>
```

I initaite the plugin in the footer

```
  $(document).ready(function(e) {

$('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();

});
```

I am getting some strange behavior, the image map/link only shows up when I resize the browser or if I run the above javascript from the console.  I have tried running the code as set timeout and setting the 'resize' function to trigger on document ready.  nothing seems to work to get the image map to show up except running this from the console or resizing the browser.

[demo](http://www.widget.devserver2012.com/jenamobile) the image map is over the red button on the second slide

Comment: I'm guessing `rwdImagEMaps` requires the images to be loaded. Try running it on the window's load event or declaring the image's width and height via html attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These file paths are wrong, your imageMap JS won't even load on the demo page:

http://www.widget.devserver2012.com/jenamobile/css/shCore.css
http://www.widget.devserver2012.com/jenamobile/css/shThemeDefault.css
http://www.widget.devserver2012.com/jenamobile/js/imageMap.js

Try to fix these first.

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: fixed but the problem persists

Comment: but that does mean it has nothing to do with this plugin as it was not even loading

Comment: You removed the image maps from the source, it won't work without them I figure.